# Module parse failed: Unexpected token - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, babeljs

i am trying to create a react component as a npm package and was following this link https://medium.com/quick-code/publish-your-own-react-component-as-npm-package-under-5-minutes-8a47f0cb92b9 and I am pretty new to this.

This is the error I am getting when I run npm.start

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 6:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   const { width, height, color, text } = props;
|   return (
>     <div
|       style={{
|         width: width || 100,
```

I looked online and seems to an issue with webpack.config but I am not sure where it is wrong in mine.

These are my files

webpack.config

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|build)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    'react': 'commonjs react' 
  }
};
```

.babelrc

```
    {
    "presets": ["env"],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        "transform-react-jsx"
    ]
}
```

src/index.js

```
import React from "react";

const ReactColorSquare = props => {
  const { width, height, color, text } = props;
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: width || 100,
        height: height || 100,
        backgroundColor: color || "blue"
      }}
    >
      {text}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReactColorSquare;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "reactnpmpackage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  }
}
```

Here is my project structure

[image]

Could you please correct where I am getting it wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `@babel/preset-react`.  Do an `npm i --save-dev @babel/preset-react`, then add it to your .babelrc file:

```js
// .babelrc

{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-react-jsx"
  ]
}
```

You might also try changing your `libraryTarget` to the universal module definition:

```js
libraryTarget: 'umd'
```

Or add `mode: development` to your `module.exports` in the webpack.config.

This solved a similar problem for me a few times.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, I did not quite understand the first step, where should i run this?

Comment: I did it and it does the same thing. `.babelrc` now looks like this `{
    "presets": [
        "env",
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        "transform-react-jsx"
    ]
}`

Comment: you would run the `npm install` command in the terminal at the root folder of your project.  Maybe try removing the "transform-react-jsx" plugin, you shouldn't need that if you have the `preset-react` preset

Comment: removed `"transform-react-jsx"` and tried it but the same error.

Comment: in webpack,config, i have `entry: './src/index.js',` is that the right path i have given seeing the folder structure picture I uploaded, it was `build/index.js` i changed to `src/index.js` hope that is right

Comment: You can also try adding `mode: development` to `module.exports` in the webpack config